# Azure function - lock others functions when working in a database area

Tags: azure-functions, locking

I have an Azure Function triggered by a queue, which is executed 16 times  in a row. This function will recieve new command from a "cluster" and run some calculations according to the already known data in the same cluster, then save the results.

Let's consider this example :

1. A function is triggered with a command about the "cars cluster"
   -> It starts the calculations
2. A second function is triggered by a command about the same "cars cluster".
   -> It sees there is already a function working on the cluster "cars", so it waits the first fonction to end.
3. A function is triggered with "boat cluster"
   -> Starts the calculations as no function is working on this cluster

So I was thinking a singleton LockerManager could do the job :

```
sealed class LongLocker
{
    private static readonly long False = 0;
    private static readonly long True = 1;

    private long locker = False;

    public int Queue { get; set; }

    public bool IsLocked()
    {
        return System.Threading.Interlocked.Read(ref locker) == True;
    }

    public void Lock()
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref locker, True);
    }

    public void Unlock()
    {
        System.Threading.Interlocked.Exchange(ref locker, False);
    }
}

public class LockerManager
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, LongLocker> lockers = new Dictionary<string, LongLocker>();

    public async Task<bool> WaitLock(string key, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        lock (lockers)
        {
            if (lockers.ContainsKey(key))
            {
                // register the wait
                lockers[key].Queue++;
            }
            else
            {
                var locker = new LongLocker();
                lockers.Add(key, locker);
                locker.Lock();
                return true;
            }
        }

        // Key already known, waits it's unlock
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (lockers[key].IsLocked())
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        });


        lock (lockers)
        {
            // Last check if another instance got time to take the lock before
            if (lockers[key].IsLocked())
                return false;

            lockers[key].Queue--;
            lockers[key].Lock();
            return true;
        }

    }

    public void Unlock(string key)
    {
        if (!lockers.ContainsKey(key))
            throw new ArgumentException("Key not known");

        lock (lockers)
        {
            var locker = new LongLocker();
            lockers.Add(key, locker);
            locker.Unlock();

            if (locker.Queue == 0)
                lockers.Remove(key);
        }
    }

}
```

There are maybe some issues in my code, I just wrote it here without testing it first. This code is more for understanding the idea.

I would like to know if you have some advice or maybe if there is something already implemented in Azure.

Thanks !

Comment: Functions are serverless so there is no guarantee that the next execution happens on the same machine/system. Instead of using writing your own in-process lock manager, I would advice to look for distributed locking like Redis cache (yes, Redis cache provides the distributed locking feature).

Comment: Using locks will only work if you configure it to only be running 1 instance. A key functionality of Azure Functions is that it may a function on tens of machines simultaneously. You may be able to use durable functions/entities for making sure only a single function can access the durable function with id of the cluster to restrict single access. Recommended would be to use another locking mechanism on the db.

Comment: Thanks for your responses. I took a look at Distributed locking, it seems a good way, but I have a very huge amount of data, and I can make more than 1M clusters. I'm afraid I'll spend lot of money by using an Azure storage. Maybe the IMemoryCache could do the work.

Comment: Very good idea for the durable orchestrator. But I don't know how to wait a durable function to be done or stack a new execution for the same instanceID